# Stateless load balanced application leads Database bottlenecks

Tags: database, rest, load-balancing, stateless

I am reading about `scalability` and `performance` of application and came across a line which states that

> "removal of the state from the application has a significant increase
>   in database load as a consequence"

I am not able to understand this line and here is why:

1. Lets say i am using `www` [or rest ] and send a request to web server which is `stateless`.
2. If my request needs an DB operation the isn't it equivalent to any `stateful` request?

What is so problematic with stateless request that increases DB load?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know the context of quoted content. You can remove (or minimize) state of the application but not in all cases. First what you can do in these cases is to move the state to database (or enterprise cache like redis) - just somehow persist state object. So, each request fetches more data from DB than in the case where a node contained data.

We try to have response time in milliseconds on my current project. Removing state would mean to load large DDD' aggregate which slowed one request by seconds for each requests and brought additional database load - it's the consequence of quoted sentence.

Comment: I was reading about oracle coherence when i came across this line. Your point makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your quoted statement is true.

> This constraint induces the properties of visibility, reliability, and
>   scalability. Visibility is improved because a monitoring system does
>   not have to look beyond a single request datum in order to determine
>   the full nature of the request. Reliability is improved because it
>   eases the task of recovering from partial failures [133]. Scalability
>   is improved because not having to store state between requests allows
>   the server component to quickly free resources, and further simplifies
>   implementation because the server doesn't have to manage resource
>   usage across requests.

According to the [Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3), removing state from the communication increases scalability and it is necessary to define the layered system constraint of REST which increases scalability even more. To make it clear: you can add caches anywhere in your system, so on the contrary the db load will decrease.